# How to avoid subsection recolouring in amsart?

Tags: sectioning, color, amsart

In the `amsart` package the text after the subsection continues at the same line as the subsection title. I want to put some coloured text just after the subsection. Here is my example:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\title{War and Peace}
\author{Leo Tolstoy}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Book One: 1805}

\subsection{Chapter 1}

{
\color{blue}
``Well, Prince, so Genoa and Lucca are now just family estates of the
Buonapartes. But I warn you, if you don't tell me that this means war, if you
still try to defend the infamies and horrors perpetrated by that Antichrist --- I
really believe he is Antichrist --- I will have nothing more to do with you and you
are no longer my friend, no longer my `faithful slave', as you call yourself!
But how do you do? I see I have frightened you --- sit down and tell me all the
news.''
}

It was in July, 1805, and the speaker was the well-known Anna Pavlovna Scherer,
maid of honor and favorite of the Empress Marya Fedorovna. With these words she
greeted Prince Vasili Kuragin, a man of high rank and importance, who was the
first to arrive at her reception. Anna Pavlovna had had a cough for some days.
She was, as she said, suffering from la grippe; grippe being then a new word in
St. Petersburg, used only by the elite.
\end{document}
```

I want first, some coloured text, and then switch back to normal one. However, the text in the braces is parsed as some additional argument of the `\subsection` command which implies that the subsection is also coloured. I tried putting additional braces before the coloured region but that doesn't help.

[image: Extract from Leo Tolstoy's "War and Peace"]

Does anyone know an elegant way to avoid this?

Comment: Could you use `\textcolor{blue}{…}` instead?

Comment: This works, thank you! I didn't know about this command

Comment: Does it work with other type of content (equations, tables) as well?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean. But sometimes the LaTeX colour stack can get confused (for reasons I don't really understand), but using `\textcolor` often works when `\color` doesn't.

Comment: @DavidPurton do you want to post as an answer? basically it works as `\textcolor` does `\leavevmode{\color....`  so the section heading is inserted as the paragraph starts before the color, unlike with `\color` which starts blue before the heading is inserted into the paragraph

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use \leavevmode. \textcolor works in your example too, but won't like if if there is a new paragraph in the argument.

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\title{War and Peace}
\author{Leo Tolstoy}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Book One: 1805}

\subsection{Chapter 1}

{\leavevmode\color{blue}%
``Well, Prince, so Genoa and Lucca are now just family estates of the
Buonapartes. But I warn you, if you don't tell me that this means war, if you
still try to defend the infamies and horrors perpetrated by that Antichrist --- I
really believe he is Antichrist --- I will have nothing more to do with you and you
are no longer my friend, no longer my `faithful slave', as you call yourself!
But how do you do? I see I have frightened you --- sit down and tell me all the
news.''
}

It was in July, 1805, and the speaker was the well-known Anna Pavlovna Scherer,
maid of honor and favorite of the Empress Marya Fedorovna. With these words she
greeted Prince Vasili Kuragin, a man of high rank and importance, who was the
first to arrive at her reception. Anna Pavlovna had had a cough for some days.
She was, as she said, suffering from la grippe; grippe being then a new word in
St. Petersburg, used only by the elite.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I accept this answer, as it has a more complete explanation on how \leavevmode works. I don't completely understand what it is, but there also seems to be a discussion here about that

Answer (score 2):

Using `\textcolor{blue}{…}` instead of `\color{blue}` produces the desired output:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\subsection{Chapter 1}

\textcolor{blue}{Blue text.}

Black text.
\end{document}
```

[image]

The reason is that inline section titles are not typeset immediately, but only when the next paragraph starts; the paragraph starts with

```
``Well
```

where the first backquote is the trigger that's put momentarily aside; only at that time TeX inserts the remembered section title and typesets the paragraph starting again from the set aside backquote. When this happens, the color has already been set to blue, so also the title appears in blue. With `\textcolor` this doesn't happen because `\textcolor` issues `\leavevmode` that triggers the start of the paragraph *before* setting the current color to blue.